# Vuetify – wait for ripple animation complete on <v-btn> click / route

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm stuck with ripple effect on `<v-btn>` (or other element that use it).

I have button on subpage that redirects to index.

```html
<v-btn to="/index">Back to index</v-btn>`
```

After
 click router backs to `/index` but vuetify ripple animation is interrupted because jump to index page is immediately. It looks terrible. Is there any option to delay click event to make ripple effect complete?

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/4a0o5zp6/

If you just click on "Back to index" button from "About" page it's jumps quickly. If you try hold down button for a while and release it it looks like it supposed to be.

Comment: I checked your jsfiddle and can't see how it's supposed to look "terrible" :/ To me, the transition looked smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ideal solution to implement - think about it ;-) - but it works.

You can listen for a `click` event on a button and delay changing routes using `setTimeout`.

**Solution**:

```js
<v-btn @click="delayAnimationGo('index')">Back to index</v-btn> // use any method name
```

```js
name: 'AboutView',
methods: {
  delayAnimationGo(destination) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$router.push(`/${destination}`)
    }, 150); // should be just right
  }
},
```

**Note**: If you want to use this functionality a lot in your components, think about creating a **mixin** or **RenderlessComponent**, so you won't repeat your code.

Comment: I've implemented something like that in `beforeRouteUpdate`.

Comment: @Daniel thats great, I'm glad you got it working. Maybe using `beforeEach` in a `router` will be easier if you use that a lot. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the ripple effect on your button:

```
<v-btn :ripple="false" >
```

To delay moving route, you could use a click event to change the route using a function instead and then use a setTimeout function to create a delay.

Comment: But I really want ripple effect.

Comment: You could delay the transition to the next page then if you want to see the ripple before moving page?

Comment: Due to specific layout I don't use `<transition>` for `<router-view>` so I'm looking to another solution.

Comment: What I meant was you can delay moving to the next page until you ripple effect has finished

Comment: The only solutions I can see are to remove the ripple or delay moving to the next page util the ripple effect is complete.